# Pass list to pytest fixture and iterates without loop

Tags: python

I am trying to write testing fucntion.

```
import pytest

@pytest.fixture(passed_list)
def test_search_through(last_state):
    # Here I want iteration through the passed_list as follows
    # last_state = passed_list[0], then last_state = passed_list[1], last_state = passed_list[2] etc. without loop
    # and depending on what will I get in last_state do some stuff
if last_state == .... :
    # .... do something
elif last_state == ....:
    # .... do something
elif last_state == ....:
    # .... do something
```

How to pass a list in this situation and is it possible to iterate through the list here with no loop?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: you should explain why you don't want a loop, to find the appropriate solution

Comment: I am newbie in Python and many things as far as I saw now can be done with no loop. And I wonder is it possible in this term..

Comment: but if you want to use all items in the list you pass, a loop seems to be the best candidate for this job

Comment: Hm.... Okay, so I just do not get the philosophy of Python yet..

Comment: This philosophy is mostly about ['make it simple'](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/).